# How can I "allow simultaneous downloads" but only for different podcast sources?

Tags: itunes, windows, podcasts

I have subscribed to some 40+ different podcasts. Occasionally, I am off-line for a few days, so some daily podcasts have several new episodes when I get back. If I select 'get all', iTunes tries to start three downloads in parallel. But many sources apparently only allow two (or even one) parallel downloads, making the third one wait.

If the proceeding downloads take too much time (> 2 minutes?), the waiting ones time-out, not to be restarted automatically.

When I get back, iTunes has downloaded a certain subset of the podcasts I wanted, timed-out the rest, and is sitting idle.

This also happens when I find a new podcast with many episodes to be downloaded. I once had to restart all timed-out downloads several times (downloading 100+ episodes for a new podcast).

My only solution until now is to disable "allow simultaneous downloads" until all has been downloaded to my PC. But this is rather slow, and also unnecessarily serializes downloads coming from different sources.

Is it possible to instruct iTunes to allow simultaneous downloads, but restrict it to downloads from different servers? That way, no timeout can prevent iTunes from downloading all, but keeping the maximum speed for parallel downloads.

If not, it would also be a little help if I can configure iTunes to only use two downloads in parallel globally; better than nothing.

Comment: My initial "take" is that the problem you're trying to solve borders on "outlier" status and is unlikely to be something Apple would provide control over. Esoteric preference settings and near-infinite configurability may be the norm with other operating systems but Apple tends to practice (and encourage) simplicity and general usability for the "90 percent". Maybe a podcast manager from a "geekier" company would better suit your needs?

Comment: I also have music, video podcasts, iTunesU, etc in my iTunes. I'd hate to split all this into multiple applications, if all would be able (in parallel!) to sync with my iPod (more than questionable). But thanks anyway, then I'll have to live with it. Unless I get some additional answer, post your comment as an answer, so I can indicate it as 'solved' and give you credit.